# Mac Snow Leopard Mcrypt extension

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard, phpmyadmin, mcrypt

Im running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6. When trying to get into phpMyAdmin, I am getting the following error:

"Cannot load mcrypt extension. Please check your PHP configuration."

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm not fantastically technical so a simple explanation would be welcome!

Cheers, Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a dl()'able extension, you need to build it. This: http://michaelgracie.com/2009/09/23/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10.6.1/ explains how.

Or, start using another PHP distribution (MacPorts springs to mind. Or perhaps Marc Liyanage is still making distributions that matter.) Myself, I've begun using the Mac Homebrew PHP packages, which finally gives me a package manager for PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS I was able to fix same error by installing `mcrypt` with yum:

```
yum search mcrypt
```